# htaccess rewrite all urls with a certain query to a parent directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Sounds actually simple and at least solvable by researching. But unfortunately I don't get it done and need to ask for help.
I want to redirect all URLs which contain certain parameters to a parent directory. My solution only works if the url doesn't contain any additional parameter:

```
RewriteRule ^cars/mercedes-brands$ /mercedes? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^motorbikes/suzuki-brands$ /suzuki[R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

Redirect works for

http://www.example.com/cars/mercedes-brands ---> http://www.example.com/mercedes

http://www.example.com/motorbikes/suzuki-brands ---> http://www.example.com/suzuki

But not for

http://www.example.com/cars/mercedes-brands/test/123

http://www.example.com/motorbikes/suzuki/12?page=3

Any ideas? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify there is (maybe) something after `mercedes-brands` and `suzuki-brands`.

Here are your 2 rules modified

```
RewriteRule ^cars/mercedes-brands(?:/.*)?$ /mercedes? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^motorbikes/suzuki-brands(?:/.*)?$ /suzuki? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```